# Showing $A_{ij} = (Ae_i, e_j)$ for matrix $A$ of complex linear operator $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ and orthonormal basis $(e_i)_{i=1}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I get stuck in the algebra when I try to prove it from definition.

Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix representing a complex linear operator $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$, suppose $(e_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and suppose we equip $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the standard complex inner product, i.e. $(x, y) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i \overline{y_i}$.

I want to show the simple property (stated in my quantum mechanics lectures) $A_{ij} = (Ae_i, e_j)$ for all $i, j$, however after expanding the inner product and expanding $Ae_i$ I can't see how to finish the algebra. So far I have:

$(Ae_i, e_j) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (Ae_i)_k \overline{e_j}_k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (\sum\limits_{l=1}^n A_{kl} e_{i_{l}}) \overline{e_j}_k$

From here on any way I try to continue, particularly trying to separate entries of $A$ and elements in the basis $e_i$, seems to hit a dead end of messy algebra. Any hints/help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can we see your calculation when you expand $A e_i$ ?

Comment: Sure, just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note:* It should be $A_{ij} = \langle A e_j, e_i \rangle$, not $\langle A e_i, e_j \rangle$.

**Observation 1:** The $i$-th component of the transform $Av$ of any column vector $v = [v_1 \quad v_2 \quad \cdots \quad v_n]'$ is $(Av)_i = {\large\sum\limits_k} A_{ik}v_k$.

**Observation 2:** The $i$-th component of the column vector representation of the $j$-th basis vector $e_j$, with respect to the same basis, is $0$ for all $i \ne j$ and $1$ for $i = j$.

From these two observations,
\begin{equation*}
(Ae_j)_i = A_{ij}.
\end{equation*}

**Observation 3:** For any vector $v = {\large\sum\limits_j} v_j e_j$, the $i$-th component can be written as an inner product (by using bilinearity of inner product and orthonormality of basis vectors)
\begin{equation*}
\langle v, e_i\rangle = \left\langle \sum_j v_j, e_j \right\rangle = \sum_j v_j \langle e_i, e_j \rangle = v_i.
\end{equation*}

Combining this with the earlier result,
\begin{equation*}
\large\boxed{
\langle Ae_j, e_i \rangle = A_{ij}
}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Note that this is independent of the particular definition of inner product for this space (it may be the standard one or anything else). It suffices that the chosen basis be orthonormal, with respect to whatever the inner product is defined to be.

Comment: yeah, this is a much neater proof without explicitly invoking the basis itself. I was hoping to do something similar myself :)

Comment: I agree with the maths you have wrote, however my professor for this module (masters level mathematical formulation of Quantum Mechanics) insists that the statement in the question is correct. Thanks for the help anyway though, this makes a lot of sense. I'm not really sure how the professor came up with the original statement, I will probably send him this to check.

Comment: Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$, $e_1 = [1\ 0]'$, $e_2 = [0\ 1]'$. Then $Ae_1 = [1\ 3]'$, $Ae_2 = [2\ 4]'$ (column vectors). \begin{align*}
\langle Ae_1, e_2 \rangle & = 3 = A_{21}\\
\langle Ae_2, e_1 \rangle & = 2 = A_{12}\end{align*}

Comment: @D.P Please show him the example too, if you can. We probably disagree on some definition.

Comment: My professor isn't responding to emails but here are the (awful) lecture notes http://docdro.id/ikQOIDK , the statement is near the top of page 2. From what I can see the only requirements are the ones I stated in the initial post although I find these notes pretty confusing so I may have missed something.

Comment: @D.P Lemme take a look. Best not call it awful if you've sent him an email with this page linked :þ

Comment: Good point, although I made sure not to send this page but instead sent the arguments posted here. Thanks for looking, I'm finding this module very... Confusing to say the least.

Comment: @D.P I couldn't glean any additional information from the notes, and I think it is most probably a mistake. Also see [here](http://hrcak.srce.hr/file/1645) and [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~durhuus/MatFys/MatFys4.pdf) (Equation 4.5).

Comment: I completely believe you and agree this is wrong, however he uses this fact (in this incorrect way) to prove multiple things throughout the lecture notes so I guess I will just have to accept it for the exam and then relearn this properly after... Thanks for the help.

Comment: @D.P I went through all the pages now. In all the places where he has used the "result", it doesn't affect the final conclusion whether you use $A_{jk}$ or $A_{kj}$. I suppose he never has to use a matrix written down as a matrix, with all the elements indexed explicitly, so it never matters. Of course, if you consistently use the opposite of the usual, and indeed ubiquitous convention of indexing, there'll be no problems.

Comment: Ah I see, so it's just lazy notation rather than incorrect proofs. This clears things up quite a bit, thanks for all the help you've given me with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, let

$$
a = Ae_i = 
\begin{bmatrix} A_{11} & \ldots & A_{1n} \\
A_{21}  &\ldots &A_{2n} \\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
A_{n1} & \ldots & A_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 0   \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
$e_i$ has a $1$ at the $i$th row and $0$ everywhere else. Hence, on multiplying, it will "pick out" $A_{i1}, A_{i2}, \ldots A_{in}$

Hence,

$$
a = Ae_i = \begin{bmatrix}A_{i1} \\ A_{i2} \\ \vdots \\ A_{in} \end{bmatrix}
$$

Next,
$$
e_j = \begin{bmatrix} 0   \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
The vector has a $1$ in the $jth$ row and $0$ everywhere else.

Hence, 
$$
\bar{e_j} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \ldots & 1 & \ldots & 0 & \end{bmatrix}
$$

So that

$$
(Ae_i, e_j) = Ae_i \bar{e_j} = \begin{bmatrix}A_{i1} \\ A_{i2} \\ \vdots \\ A_{in} \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \ldots & 1 & \ldots & 0 & \end{bmatrix} = A_{ij}
$$

Comment: Thanks, but (perhaps I should a letter other than e) I meant for general orthonormal basis $e_i$ rather than the standard basis. I was thinking of using a change of basis matrix to change to this basis and finishing as in this answer however, I just can't seem to get the algebra to work.

Comment: Yes, changing to the standard basis would also work as an argument. Where exactly are you getting stuck? During the change of basis, remember that your basis vectors change, and your matrix $A_{ij}$ _also_ changes. Maybe you didn't take that into account?

Comment: Honestly I don't really know how to set it up, if we have $P$ changing the basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ from $(\phi_i)$ (non-standard) to $(e_i)$ (standard) and we start with $(A\phi_i, \phi_j)$ I am confused as to how to get $(Ae_i, e_j)$ from this. I think I have forgotten some obvious result from linear algebra, but the Wikipedia pages I've been trawling are being very unhelpful in letting me find these results. That is, I can't remember how $P, \phi_i$ and $e_i$ interact with each other and I can't find any good resource to recall the information from.

Comment: @D.P The matrix $A$ is a representation of the linear operator *relative to some specific basis*. Relative that basis, the basis vectors *are* $e_j$, that is, coordinate vectors with a $1$ in the $j$th place and zeroes everywhere else. If you change basis, both your basis vectors and the matrix $A$ change, so you should be talking about $[A]_\phi$ and $[A]_e$. If you write out $([A]_\phi\phi_i,\phi_j)$ in terms of the original basis and the change-of-basis matrix, I believe you’ll find that the latter will cancel out and you’ll be left with $([A]_ee_i,e_j)$.

Comment: $Ae_i$ should have components $A_{1i}, A_{2i},\ldots$. This is why your final answer matches the (erroneous) statement in the question. Otherwise you'd finally get $A_{ji}$, which is correct.